# Intel graphics driver

Tags: gpu, linux-device-driver, graphics3d

I’m interested in Linux graphics stack, especially how a linux graphics driver works. I learnt that Intel offers open source graphics drivers for linux for their chips and I have an old laptop running intel p6200 which has a built-in graphics card, so I think it’s a good idea to take the laptop as a playground, however I can’t find the source code for intel graphics cards in the kernel code, the links on 01.org is broken. So can anybody tell me where is code and how to build it, and more over, can anybody give some documentation on how a graphics driver woks?

Comment: They are in the Linux kernel, location is most probably something like *drivers/gpu/drm/i915/*.

Comment: @0andriy thanks so much for your reply, I find the directory you mentioned